# What is the proper way to get the item with the following query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the two functions below but one work and the other is throwing the error:

```
[ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
// this works
async function getUserByEmail(email) {
    var service = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: REGION });
    var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: service });

    var params = { 
        TableName : TABLE,
        Key: {
            'email': email
        }
    };

    return dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
}


// this throws an error
async function getUserById(id) {
    var service = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: REGION });
    var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: service });

    var params = { 
        TableName : TABLE,
        Key: {
            'id': id
        }
    };

    return dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
}
```

The table is:

```
{ email, user, id }
```

The Partition key is `email` and there is no sort key.

My guess is that the `key` and value can only be `email` but then how do you filter on a different column?

Comment: you need to create secondary index (AWS recommends Global over Local): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Answer (score 1):

To get an item using a non-key attributes you would need to create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) and setting the users `ID` as the partition key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

As items on a GSI are not required to be unique, you will need to use `query` instead of the `get` API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Another tip is to not create your clients inside your methods, you should create one client and share its state across all methods. This will help reduce your latency and memory overhead.

Comment: Secondary? What if I have many other non-key attributes? If I want to query by city or state or age or 20 other values? Do I have create GSI's for each?

Comment: Yes. If you have access patterns which need to obtain data based on 20+ attributes then DynamoDB would not be a great fit on its own. If you need the performance of DynamoDB but still need query flexibility then consider complimenting DynamoDB with OpenSearch.

Comment: So I have to create an index and then pass in a different search object and use query?

Comment: "Another tip is to not create your clients inside your methods", ok thanks

Comment: Yea, an index is essentially a view for your data. Allowing you to efficiently read using a different key. Of course you could use a full table Scan to do it without an index, but it's not scalable and can be expensive in performance and cost when the table size grows.